Restrict zooming out by minimum scale in PhotoView flutter
I read some of the read me and the docs and it doesn't show the best "normal" settings of the widget PhotoView from the package photo_view flutter
here is my code
```dart

class PhotoViewerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotoViewerScreen(this.image, {super.key});

  final ImageProvider image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.pop();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
          ),
          title: Text(
            "عرض الصورة",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium?.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
                  fontFamily: "Alexandria",
                  fontSize: 17.25,
                ),
          ),
        ),
        body: PhotoView(
          imageProvider: image,
          minScale: 1.0,
          maxScale: 3.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


minScale set to 1.0 doesn't work
For the image to not shrink lower than the 1.0 scale

seems like I need to set the minScale to contain by using this
/// ...
 body: PhotoView(
          imageProvider: image,
          minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained, // use this
          maxScale: 3.0,
        ),

